# Is it possible to add a child to a node in swift, conditionally

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, try-catch

I am making a SpriteKit game, and I have a block that executes a few times per second. When it executes, asteroids are created and added to the world node. After a few seconds of playing, an error occurs when adding them to the `worldNode` (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). The code is shown below

```
 let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)
 let spawnAsteroid = SKAction.runBlock() {
    let asteroid = Asteroid(player: self.player, screenSize: self.size)
    self.worldNode.addChild(asteroid)
 }
 let makeAsteroid = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawnAsteroid])
 runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(makeAsteroid))
```

I am wondering if it is possible to wrap the line `self.worldNode.addChild(asteroid)` in a `try/catch` or something similar in order to avoiding crashing? *note that each asteroid has an internal timer that will remove it from its parent after a few seconds*

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the error message?

Comment: unfortunately the only message it gives me is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_THREAD (code=1, address 0X0)

Comment: this code on its own should be fine.  you must be doing something else to cause the crash

Comment: Where is "worldNode" defined? Is it an implicitly unwrapped optional? If so, add the ? operator after it

Comment: @C.Greene I don't think a try/catch is the answer. Can you share how you create the Asteroid? You are passing in your player so my best guess is there is an issue with that. Everything else appears to look fine from first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others commented:

1. try/catch is not the answer, if there is an error it should be fixed
2. your code (at least the one we can see) looks correct

### The problem

If the line that causes the error is

```
self.worldNode.addChild(asteroid)
```

I can guess that:

1. you declared `worldNode` as an **Implicitly Unwrapped Optional**

   ```
   var worldNode: SKNode!
   ```
2. somewhere you are setting `worldNode` to `nil`

   ```
   self.worldNode = nil
   ```

So, later one, when your `SKAction` tries to invoke `addChild` on a `nil` variable you get the error.

Does my explanation match with the other code in your project? If it does I can suggest 2 solutions

### Solution 1

You should stop setting `worldNode` to `nil`.

### Solution 2

Or, if you really need to set `worldNode` to `nil`, you should stop your action immediately before.

First of all give the action a key (so you'll be able to retrieve it later on)

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(makeAsteroid), withKey: "addAsteroidForever")
```

then before setting `self.worldNode = nil` stop the action

```
self.removeActionForKey("addAsteroidForever")
```

Comment: You are correct, the world node was declared like so:                                var worldNode: SKNode!  After fixing that, I still ran into the error a few seconds after starting the game. I did manage to find a work around which is to create 50 asteroids at the start of the game and set their hidden attribute to true when they are not in use (object pooling). I'll continue to poke at this code and figure out what is causing this error. Thanks for your answers